# How to configure a tool to open shell or run a shell command?

Tags: configuration, eclipse

I'm `Manjaro`, an `Arch` based distribution, and I'm using `Eclipse` (An IDE). `Eclipse` has a plugin to facilitate some quick commands for selected files and folders.

Some of these commands are:

1. Shell Open
2. Shell Run
3. Explore

I managed to configure the `Explore` command by setting it's value to `thunar {2}`, which tells `thunar`, the file manager on `Manjaro` to open the given path.

But I'm unable to configure the first 2 commands, `Shell Open` and `Shell Run`. I tried setting `Shell Open` to `bash {1}` but nothing happened !

Why did nothing happen and what should I use to open a shell for the given path ? Would the same command work for the `Shell Run` command ?

[image]

Comment: It didn't work. I opened the shell and ran `gnome-terminal` and I was prompted that this command doesn't exist. My desktop environment is XFCE, should this be key to solving my case ?

Comment: Yep, using `xfce4-terminal`, thanks man